# Two equivalent strings show as Unequal in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, operators

I have two identical strings (I literally copied and pasted `string1` and just changed the name to `string2`). They are interpreted as unequal:

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const string1 = `{
    meta:
            Club = "chess club"
            Id = "7431"
            Time ="July 6, 2021"
            Report = "3209_321_1"
    data:
            $6523 = {something}
            $val_1 = {717}
    another-thing:
            ($thing)
}`;

  const string2 = `{
  meta:
          Club = "chess club"
          Id = "7431"
          Time ="July 6, 2021"
          Report = "3209_321_1"
  data:
          $6523 = {something}
          $val_1 = {717}
  another-thing:
          ($thing)
}`;

  return (
    <div className="App">
        {string1 === string2 ? "equal" : "not equal"}  // outputting "not equal"
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried `===`, `==`, and Lodash's `isEqual(string1, string2)`. All of them return "not equal".

Please check my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-hertz-ks8xkk?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: because they are different, check it online https://www.diffchecker.com/NRBJLwGI

Comment: it has indentation issue

Comment: If you don't care about white spaces, just use `string1.trim === string2.trim` for equality check

Answer (score 1):

You have extra indentation in the first string compared to the second string so there is more whitespace in the first string causing them to be not equal check the following example.

Here is yours

```js
  const string1 = `{
    meta:
            Club = "chess club"
            Id = "7431"
            Time ="July 6, 2021"
            Report = "3209_321_1"
    data:
            $6523 = {something}
            $val_1 = {717}
    another-thing:
            ($thing)
}`;

  const string2 = `{
  meta:
          Club = "chess club"
          Id = "7431"
          Time ="July 6, 2021"
          Report = "3209_321_1"
  data:
          $6523 = {something}
          $val_1 = {717}
  another-thing:
          ($thing)
}`;

console.log(string1 === string2)
```

vs what it should be for them to be equal:

```js
  const string1 = `{
    meta:
            Club = "chess club"
            Id = "7431"
            Time ="July 6, 2021"
            Report = "3209_321_1"
    data:
            $6523 = {something}
            $val_1 = {717}
    another-thing:
            ($thing)
}`;

  const string2 = `{
    meta:
            Club = "chess club"
            Id = "7431"
            Time ="July 6, 2021"
            Report = "3209_321_1"
    data:
            $6523 = {something}
            $val_1 = {717}
    another-thing:
            ($thing)
}`;

console.log(string1 === string2)
```

As you can see the extra indentation is causing the issue. Look at the objects keys are lined up together between the first and second string in the bottom example vs they are not in the first example.